# regex pattern in java.matches-method

Tags: java, regex

I need to get the regex pattern for the following sequence of numbers:

```
X.XXX.XXX-X
```

Every `X` is one number.

I've already tried:

```
pattern: `partnerNumberOnFirstPage = "*.*.*-*"`

if (stringContent.matches(partnerNumberOnFirstPage)){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

How can I do that? And do I implement it right? I don't want to use `*` because I need exactly the number of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^\d\.\d\d\d\.\d\d\d-\d$
```

I'm not sure but I think you have to double escape in java, so:

```
^\\d\\.\\d{3}\\.\\d{3}-\\d$
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways:

```
\d\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d
```

or

```
\d(?:\.\d{3}){2}-\d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^\\d\\.\\d{3}\\.\\d{3}-\\d$
```

- **^** matches the start of a string
- **$** matches the end of a stringg
- \\ java requires a double escape (for \d and .)
- **\d** matches any single number (0-9)
- **{X}** means the preceding pattern chunk must occur X times, {X,Y} also works if you're flexible

Yes, your implementation looks great!

Also note, you can remove the start/end tags if you need to match anywhere in a string.